# Inkscape fit page to selection shortcut

Tags: vector, inkscape

I heve this issue in Inkscape:

```
file>document properties
```

Won't open. Not even after cache clear or PC reboot.
I have to resize the page to the current selection.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I solved by finding the Shortcut to shrink the page on the selection:

```
CTRL + SHIFT + R
```